# jQuery drag and drop, validating draggable id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, undefined

I've built a really simple drag and drop activity.
When an answer is dropped on the drop area, its id is stored in a variable called 'answer'.
When the submit button is hit it runs a function called validate which checks if the variable answer has an id of 'correct' stored inside of it.

The problem is, when I hit the submit button it doesn't run the validate function because it says 'the variable answer is not defined'.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Yay for drap and drops!</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style> div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#correct").draggable(); //I have drag capability now!
    $("#wrong").draggable();  //I have drag capability now!
    $("#dropArea1").droppable({
      drop: function(event,ui) {
      var answer = ui.draggable.attr("id");
      console.log(answer);
      }
  });
});  

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="correct">
  <p>CORRECT ANSWER</p>
</div>

<div id="wrong">
  <p>WRONG ANSWER</p>
</div>

<div id="dropArea1">
  <p>I'm the drop area</p>
</div>
<script>
  function validate() {
    if (answer == ("#correct")) {
      window.location.replace("www.google.com") //correct! redirect web page to next activity
    }

    else {
      window.alert("Incorrect, try again") //incorrect, try again
    }
  }
</script>
<button onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `answer` is defined as variable local to `drop` handler, it's not in scope of `validate` function. Make sure that 1) either those two functions share the same state, or 2) `validate()` can extract the dropped answer id on their own. Besides, even if it worked, you wouldn't get any correct answers, as you attempt to compare 'correct' with '#correct' (hash sign is not needed here).

Answer (score 0):

One option to fix this is to define the variable `answer` outside of the `$(document).ready()` scope, like this:

```
var answer = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#correct").draggable(); //I have drag capability now!
  $("#wrong").draggable();  //I have drag capability now!
  $("#dropArea1").droppable({
    drop: function(event,ui) {
    answer = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    console.log(answer);
    }
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that!! Thankyou SOOO much (^__^) You've saved the day